# relationship between a function and its tangent lines

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = 2x^3−3x^2−6x+ 2$.
How should I find the equations of all tangent lines to $f$ which are parallel to the line $y= 6x$?
I need to express the tangent lines in $y=mx+b$ form.

My thoughts:
For now, I know that if we are looking for a line tangent to a point on a function, we can try to look into the change in rise over change in horizon at that instantaneous point. If we get closer and closer the that point in both left and right side of that point, we will get closer to the actual rate of change.

Going back to the actual question, I am not sure how to connect the concept and operate on that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? I am so sorry but I don't know where to start. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: This kind of exercises are typical when one is learning differential calculus. Do you know the concept of derivative?

Comment: Yes, I am learning it. A function represents the relationship of variables and finding the (first) derivative of this function is finding the change of y relative to x at a certain point on that function, correct? (maybe? I am not so sure.)

Comment: @jjagmath Oh I see. So this is a typical entry level question to test understanding. Could you shed some light on how to approach question like this?